# InvalidOperationException when iterating over LINQ-to-SQL Queryable

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, linq-to-sql, mono

I am mapping data from a SQLite database to C# objects using LINQ to SQL. Everything works perfectly when I'm running it inside a Visual Studio project, but for some reason I can't get it to work in Unity.

The very simplified code goes something like this:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

var connectionString = "Data Source=" + filePath + ";DbLinqProvider=SQLite;Version=3;";
var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
var context = new DataContext(connection);

foreach (Output output in context.GetTable<Output>())
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(output.ID);
}
```

But in the head of the `foreach` an InvalidOperationException is thrown, saying *"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"*.

- I know that the mapping works, because it does in Visual Studio.
- I know that the database connectivity works, because it does when using "normal" `DbCommand`s.
- I'm still a bit unsure about the included DLLs, but again, I tested it with exactly those ones (contrary to the "built in" ones) in VS and it worked. In my Assets folder I have `System.Data.dll`, `System.Data.Linq.dll`, `Mono.Data.Sqlite` from the Mono install, and `sqlite3.dll` and `sqlite3.def` from the SQLite website.

The Exception goes as follows:

```
InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[MemberInfo] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate, Fallback fallback)
System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[MemberInfo] (IEnumerable`1 source)
DbLinq.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaAssociation..ctor (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.    AssociationAttribute attribute, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaDataMember metaDataMember)
DbLinq.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaType+<GetAssociations>c__Iterator5.MoveNext ()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaAssociation].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) (at /    Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:128)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaAssociation]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) (at /Users/    builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:65)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[MetaAssociation] (IEnumerable`1 source)
DbLinq.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaType.get_Associations ()
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SetEntitySetsQueries (System.Object entity)
System.Data.Linq.DataContext._GetOrRegisterEntity (System.Object entity)
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.Register (System.Object entity)
DbLinq.Data.Linq.Sugar.Implementation.QueryRunner.Select[Output] (DbLinq.Data.Linq.Sugar.SelectQuery selectQuery)
DbLinq.Data.Linq.Implementation.QueryProvider`1[Bitcoin.Output].GetEnumerator ()
System.Data.Linq.Table`1[Bitcoin.Output].GetEnumerator ()
DAO.SQLiteDAO.test (System.String filePath) (at Assets/DAO/SQLiteDAO.cs:103)
DAO.SQLiteDAO..ctor (System.String filePath) (at Assets/DAO/SQLiteDAO.cs:25)
SphereSpawner.Start () (at Assets/SphereSpawner.cs:30)
```

I read everything here that seems similar, but I never actively use `Single()` on anything, so that cannot be it; and I'm quite sure that the list isn't empty, either. It shouldn't be, at least.

Please help, I'm losing my mind here :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, apparently the mapping was the problem after all. It seems like Mono.Data.Sqlite needs more explicit attributes than System.Data.SQLite, and my solution that worked perfectly in the latter didn't in the former.

I found that:

- All `Association`s must have a `Name` specified.
- `IsForeignKey=true` must be set when applicable.
- Apparently, IDs that are used as foreign keys in an `Association` cannot be stored in a public `Column` member; instead, they must be wrapped in a property using `Storage="privateMember"`. In the end, I implemented every `Column` mapping as a property, just to be sure.